# What is a Flipped Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Flipped Word™.

Use the following examples below to uncover the rule.

[image: Flipped Words™]

Here is a CSV version.

```
Flipped Words™,Not Flipped Words™
boosts,speed
dumps,drop
mound,hill
blowup,explode
unbolt,tighten
downtown,city
bomb,dynamite
box,crate
quod,court
slump,streak
```

Comment: ...That's not CSV, unless the words on the left have a single leading space and the ones on the right have two or three. See [CSV](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Alrighty then. I'll fix that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess

> Flipped words are words in which all letters can be flipped upside down to form another letter.
>  boosts -> poosfs
>  dumps -> qnwbs
>  mound -> wonuq
>  blowup -> plomnb
>  unbolt -> wnupolf
>  downtown -> qomufomu
>  bomb -> powp
>  box -> pox
>  quod -> dnoq
>  slump -> slnwb

Not Flipped words

> contain at least one letter that cannot be flipped, e.g. i, e or r

Comment: I guess I made it too easy... Lol. I'll give you the check once I can

Comment: What is meant by "flipped"? t -> f is reflection over a horizontal axis, but s -> s is not; it's rotation.

Comment: I should've guessed by the hint "flipped word"... And here I was about to write a python brute force solver script.

Comment: @LarsH The t was just meant to be a sort of deformed t when flipped, but there's a little curve at the bottom which worked well with f. I realized after I had written and posted the puzzle so I left it. Good eye with the s though. I didn't even stop to think about that one! In hindsight, this wasn't a too good puzzle, but I'm working on a tougher one now